# How to make my Custom Action Bar Transparent

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I am new to Android and working on my first android app. For my app I need a transparent Action Bar with a Navigation Drawer button. Everything is working fine except the color of the Action Bar. It is having blue color instead of transparent. I have tried various ways to make it transparent but its still blue. Can someone please help me out with my code:

**custom_navigation_bar.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**styles.xml:**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Themes for Navigation Drawer -->
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
           parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">#00000000</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:background">#00000000</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**Java Code Snippet:**

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //Setting Transparent Color for Action Bar
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#00000000")));
```

Comment: What is the use of the fully transparent Action Bar?

Comment: Are you asking for the background of the actionBar to be transparent?

Comment: The thing is I have a navigation drawer. I want the action bar background to be fully transparent and the action bar should overlap the below layouts. The layout below it is having some image. Only thing visible on the action bar should be the button that toggles the Navigation drawer.

Answer (score 2):

You can just set the toolbar background to transparent :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#00000000"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

you have one item in base theme windowActionBarOverlay set it to true and set action bar color to transparent.

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/text_color</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```